# run command as string in morphia

Tags: string, mongodb, command, morphia

can I run a query in morphia to which I write the command as String?

somehing like this:

```
query.executeCommand("db.collection.find()");
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  Neither Morphia nor the Java driver (nor any driver that I'm aware of) support the shell syntax.

Comment: thats what I was afraid of :/ thanks. Do you have any idea why isnt this function implemented?